# Bluetooth device appearing and shortly after disappearing Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, bluetooth, configuration, connection, headphones

I am attempting to connecting a pair of Bluetooth headphones in Ubuntu however, when I attempt to pair the headphones the name of the headphones(QY7) will appear briefly and then disappear a few moments later. Is there is way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A good way to fix this would be to install Blueman Bluetooth Manager.After you installed it If you however happen to get the "Connection Failed: Stream setup failed".Then do this fix I found from tuxdiary.com:

1.Edit /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf and uncomment the following line:

```
AutoConnect=true
```

2.Run the following command to install latest packages for blueman and related modules:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blueman/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade blueman
```

3.Run blueman-applet. Right click on the panel applet and turn bluetooth on.

4.The old profie of you bluetooth device would still be there, remove it. Right click on the blueman-panel applet and select Setup New Device. Complete the wizard for your device.

5.Logout and login.

Comment: My device doesn't show in the wizard

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but can you tell me the model number and brand of your headphones?